# How can I print a new line in a file in assembly (nasm)?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I would like to print data in a file separated with an endline. I imagined like this:

```
segment data use32 class=data
 format db "/n %d",0
segment code use32 class=code
   start:
       push dword mod_acces
       push dword filename
       call [fopen]
       add esp,4*2
       
       mov [descriptor], eax

       push dword 10
       push dword format
       push dword [descriptor]
       call [fprintf]
       add esp,4*3
        
      ;fclose()
```

But it's not working.

Comment: The character code for a newly is 10.  Try a string like `db 10, 0` or `db "%d", 10, 0`.

Comment: Is that forward slash and `n` supposed to be `\n`?  That has to be inside backticks, not single or double quotes, for C-style escapes to work.